# How to get functionalities of Fragment Activity in other Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have created a `Fragment Activity`, It displays `Google Map` and does other stuff.

Now  i have another `Activity`, I want to use all the functionalities of `Fragment Activity` into my new `Activity`.

If i had Fragment, i would have easily used it in my new layout like following.

```
   <fragment
        android:id="@+id/calendarFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"  
        class="com.activities.fragments.HeaderFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/header_fragment" />
```

But now i am using `FragmentActivity`, i cannot use above mentioned code, if i use it it gives me following error message

```
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException
```

and it obvious, as i passing `FragmentActivity` into `Activity`.

Kindly guide me how to reuse `FragmentActivity`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way would be to use inheritance. Basically make 1 FragmentActivity as the base and then make implementation A (which you already have) that extends the FragmentActivity and then make implementation B which also extends it but does some things differently. It all depends on how much you want to reuse...

Just to make it completely clear. Your current FragmentActivity will be the base. Implementation A will not change very much, while B might change a lot...

Comment: Thanks a lot, Your advice make things very clear, I have done ditto. I want to use all the functionalities of Parent Activity, the child will have some additional functionalities.  Now in child i am extending it from parent, but it displaying nothing in the layout. What changes i need to make in child to display the parent elements in child layout.

Comment: @Kirmani88 you need to setcontentview in the oncreate. This will properly be a different layout for each child but remember if you reference any layout it should have the same id in both or you should make reference to the same field value.